# Change function into dependencyproperty

Tags: c#, xaml, dependency-properties

I am new to XAML and WPF and I am learning about DependencyProperty and Path. For example, I have a function like this

```
public byte[] DownloadPicture()
{
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    byte[] data;
    data = webClient.DownloadData("https://graph.facebook.com/4/picture&type=large");       
    return data;
}
```

and I have dependencyproperty like this

```
public static DependencyProperty DownloadPicProperty = 
DependencyProperty.Register("DownloadPic", typeof(byte), 
    typeof(ImageControl), new PropertyMetadata(false));
```

How can I connect the DependencyProperty with the DownloadPicture function I wrote? Any suggestions? What should I write in the CLR wrapper?

Comment: Maybe you can explain what the intention is. 'Connect the DependencyProperty' can mean many things. Do you want to set the value? Do you want to download the picture if it is null?

Comment: I want to set the value. But I don't want to download the picture if it is null. I read about change function into dependencyproperty so I can use the data binding, but still no luck with that because I am new at XAML. Can you help me?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. If you think of a DependencyProperty like a standard property on the control, how are you linking your method to the property? Is the method setting the property? What is the type of the property? Is it a string or an array of bytes?

Comment: @Cameron, yeah I want to ask how to link the method to the property. The method will set the property. The type of the property should be byte.

Comment: @Cameron I'm sorry. I mean byte[]. I am a total newbie in XAML, so I really need your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get and set the value of a dependency property by adding a standard property to the control as well.

```
public static DependencyProperty DownloadPicProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("DownloadPic", typeof(byte[]), typeof(ImageControl));

public byte[] DownloadPic
{
    get { return (byte[])GetValue(DownloadPicProperty); }
    set { SetValue(DownloadPicProperty, value); }
}

...
ImageControl imageControl = ...;
imageControl.DownloadPic = DownloadPicture();
```